# How to use findViewById() in robolectric

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, robolectric, robolectric-gradle-plugin

I simply want to test with robolectric if a certain view is visible in a fragment.
My unit test looks like this:

```
ActivityController controller = Robolectric.buildActivity(FragmentActivity.class);
FragmentActivity activity = (FragmentActivity) controller.create().start().resume().visible().get();

F fragment = new MyFragment();
activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .add(fragment, FRAGMENT_TAG).commit();


View view = fragment.getView().findViewById(R.id.my_view);
assertEquals(view.getVisibility(), View.VISIBLE);
```

I'm using the latest android gradle plugin 1.1.3, robolectirc 2.4 and robolectric gradle plugin 1.0.1 and my unit test is in the `test` folder (not `androidTest`). I can't compile that code, because the compiler can't resolve `R.java`.

My `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    jcenter()
  }

  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.3'
    classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.4'
    classpath 'org.robolectric:robolectric-gradle-plugin:1.0.1'
  }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'
apply plugin: 'org.robolectric'


android { ... }

dependencies {
  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

  // Testing
  testCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:2.4'
  testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

  // Other dependencies
  ...
}
```

How do I write such a unit test with robolectric?

Update:
Here is the complete code:

```
public class TestFragment extends Fragment {

  @Override public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
      Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_listview_ptr, container, false);
  }
}


public class MyFragmentTest {

  private static final String FRAGMENT_TAG = "fragment";
  private ActivityController controller;
  private FragmentActivity activity;

  @Test
  protected void displaysContentView(boolean pullToRefreshSupported) {

    controller = Robolectric.buildActivity(FragmentActivity.class);
    activity = (FragmentActivity) controller.create().start().resume().visible().get();
    Fragment fragment = new TestFragment();

    FragmentManager manager = activity.getSupportFragmentManager();
    manager.beginTransaction()
        .add(fragment, FRAGMENT_TAG).commit();

    // Compile errors here
    View loadingView = fragment.getView().findViewById(R.id.loadingView);
    View contentView = fragment.getView().findViewById(R.id.contentView);
    View errorView = fragment.getView().findViewById(R.id.loadingView);

    Assert.assertNotSame(loadingView.getVisibility(), View.VISIBLE);
    Assert.assertNotSame(errorView.getVisibility(), View.VISIBLE);
    Assert.assertEquals(contentView.getVisibility(), View.VISIBLE);
  }
}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center">


<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
      android:id="@+id/pull_to_refresh"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/contentView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:fadingEdge="none"
        android:fastScrollEnabled="false"
        android:footerDividersEnabled="false"
        android:headerDividersEnabled="false"
        android:listSelector="@color/transparent"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
        android:smoothScrollbar="false"
        android:scrollbars="none"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

<TextView
      android:id="@+id/errorView"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:visibility="gone"
      android:text="@string/error_loading_retry"
      android:layout_gravity="center"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:layout_centerInParent="true"
      android:drawableTop="@drawable/error_no_connection"
      android:drawablePadding="12dp"
      android:textColor="@color/gray_dark"
      android:padding="16dp"
      />

<fr.castorflex.android.circularprogressbar.CircularProgressBar
      android:id="@+id/loadingView"
      android:layout_width="40dp"
      android:layout_height="40dp"
      android:indeterminate="true"
      android:layout_gravity="center"
      android:layout_centerInParent="true"
      android:visibility="gone"
      />

</FrameLayout>
```

The code can be found here: https://github.com/sockeqwe/RobolectircTest

Comment: Can you share your `build.gradle` file? First 4 lines could be replaced with next line `F fragment = new MyFragment(); FragmentTestUtil.startVisibleFragment( fragment );`

Comment: I have added the `build.gradle` file. I know that `FragmentTestUtils` can be used instead. The reason I'm not using  `FragmentTestUtils` is that I'm not using `FragmentActivity` but another Activity that uses a special dagger module with testing mocks. For simplicity reasons I left that out.

Comment: Post all of your code.

Comment: @JaredBurrows I have added my code

Comment: Are tests in the separate module?

Comment: No, both are in the same module. `TestFragment` is in `src/main/java` and `MyFragmentTest` is in `src/test/java`

Comment: @sockeqwe How is the testing coming? A newer version of the plugin is out: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system, support the testing of libraries now! *1.2.0-beta1 (2015/03/25)*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Update:

I would suggest to go ahead and update to Robolectric 3.0.

Annotate your classes with:

```
@RunWith(CustomRobolectricRunner.class)
@Config(emulateSdk = 21, reportSdk = 21)
```

RobolectricGradleTestRunner.java:

https://github.com/nenick/AndroidStudioAndRobolectric/blob/master/app/src/test/java/com/example/myapplication/CustomRobolectricRunner.java

Update your `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application' // <-- for some reason, com.android.library is not working correctly
apply plugin: 'org.robolectric'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'org.apache.maven:maven-ant-tasks:2.1.3'
    testCompile('org.robolectric:shadows-support-v4:3.0-SNAPSHOT') {
        exclude group: 'commons-logging', module: 'commons-logging'
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient'
    }
}
```

### Original:

Using `Robolectric.buildActivity(FragmentActivity.class);` is for testing `Activity`s.

Please edit your `MyFragmentTest` to look like this:

```
@RunWith(CustomRobolectricRunner.class)
@Config(emulateSdk = 21, reportSdk = 21)
public class MyFragmentTest {

  @Test
  public void testAppFragmentStart() {
    final TestFragment fragment = new TestFragment();

    SupportFragmentTestUtil.startFragment(fragment, FragmentActivity.class);

    // My test examples - hamcrest matchers
    Assert.assertThat(fragment, CoreMatchers.not(CoreMatchers.nullValue()));
    Assert.assertThat(fragment.getView(), CoreMatchers.not(CoreMatchers.nullValue()));
    Assert.assertThat(fragment.getActivity(), CoreMatchers.not(CoreMatchers.nullValue()));
    Assert.assertThat(fragment.getActivity(), CoreMatchers.instanceOf(FragmentActivity.class));

    // Your tests
    View loadingView = fragment.getView().findViewById(R.id.loadingView);
    View contentView = fragment.getView().findViewById(R.id.contentView);
    View errorView = fragment.getView().findViewById(R.id.errorView);

    Assert.assertNotSame(loadingView.getVisibility(), View.VISIBLE);
    Assert.assertNotSame(errorView.getVisibility(), View.VISIBLE);
    Assert.assertEquals(contentView.getVisibility(), View.VISIBLE);
  }
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73589/discussion-on-answer-by-jared-burrows-how-to-use-findviewbyid-in-robolectric).