# Robolectric No tests found

Tags: android, junit, android-studio, robolectric

I started with robolectric in android studio. 
I would run a simple example, but i have this error

Running tests
Test running started
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: No tests found in com.example.myApp.AuthenticationActivityTest
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:191)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:176)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:555)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1837)

### Test class

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class AuthenticationActivityTest {

@Test
public void checkAccountType() throws Exception{
    String accType = new AuthenticationActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.account_type);
    assertThat(accType,equalTo("com.example.myApp"));
}
}
```

### Gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'org.robolectric' //Robolectric

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myApp"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            debuggable true
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.12' //Robolectric
    androidTestCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:2.4' //Robolectric
}
```

## Update

when i add the testInstrumentationRunner in default config in the gradle like:

```
testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
```

the robolectic tests become recognized, but i got this error:

```
com.example.myApp.AuthenticationActivityTest > testAccountType[small(AVD) - 5.0.2] FAILED 
java.lang.NullPointerException: parentLoader == null && !nullAllowed
at java.lang.ClassLoader.<init>(ClassLoader.java:210)
:app:connectedAndroidTest FAILED
```

Comment: Are you running them in Android Studio? Are you running them as instrumental tests (Android test)?

Comment: I'm using Android studio. I try running them as android test and as junit but i get the same error.

Comment: I would say it is not possible to run `Robolectic` tests in Android Studio. I telling this because I don't know yet stable solution how to run tests with `android gradle` plugin v1.1.x and `Robolectric` inside the studio. So I would suggest you to concentrate on running tests from command line. Can you run `gradle clean testDebug` from the command line?

Comment: gradle clear testDebug give BUILD SUCCESSFUL.

Comment: As expected. If it is enough for you I would close the question

Comment: no i would say that the BUILD SUCCESSFUL, but during execution of test I get **Running tests Test running started junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: No tests found**

Comment: Did you read my comment about running tests from Android Studio?

Comment: I run the test from the command line, but i get in the index.html : 0 tests, 0 failures ,0 ignored

Comment: Ah sorry, what is your folders structure? Can you move test to `src/test`. Please add suggestion from answer below so Android Studio will recognise test

Comment: the tests class are placed in **src/androidTest/java/com.example.myApp**. I created a test that extends `ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2` (without robolectric) and it work (command : `gradlew connectedAndroidTest`
). I think that the problem is in my robolectric's config.

Comment: @houssine Please follow my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29188505/950427. If you are using `ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2`, keep those in `androidTest`, the Robolectric tests should be in `test`.

Comment: Adding on, you should be using Robolectric 3.0+ and `RobolectricGradleTestRunner`, you do not need to add `android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner`.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding;

```
sourceSets {
    androidTest {
        setRoot('src/test')
    }
}
```

To your build.gradle 'android' closure, directed at your tests directory.

Also are you running the tests directly from Android Studio? I have had issues with this previously, try running them using the gradle test command from the terminal.

Comment: same problem. I'm using android studio. But if i run the 'ApplicationTest' (generate from android studio) it work successfully.

Comment: You do not have to do this. This is for when he does not have that folder.