# Roboelectric 3.0 testing fragments

Tags: android, robolectric, android-testing

I am new to Roboelectric testing.
I am trying to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29173071/how-to-use-findviewbyid-in-robolectric)  post to test fragments. I am using  following as dependency

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile "org.robolectric:robolectric:3.0"
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.1.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
```

}

But this import is giving me compilation issues, and I am not able to resolve the symbol SupportFragmentTestUtil to start with. Kindly guide me what I am missing??

```
org.robolectric.shadows.support.v4.SupportFragmentTestUtil
```

Comment: Do not copy and paste. Use `SupportFragmentTestUtil` with `testCompile "org.robolectric:robolectric:3.0"`

Comment: Thanks Jared for your interest. I have updated my problem. I am surprised , I dont see this import , there is no support package

Comment: Please see @Nicks answer.

Comment: ohhh great, it worked. But shouldn't this be documented somewhere for android newbies like me.

Comment: It shouldnt be documented? You mean it should? It is on the robolectric wiki on github.

Comment: Hi Jared,  can you point me the link. I happened to see https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric  and  http://robolectric.org/getting-started/   and in both links, nowhere i was able to figure out the use of support library dependency.It will be helpful for me for future reference.

Comment: Here: https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/wiki/2.4-to-3.0-Upgrade-Guide

Comment: guys!!! can you guide me in this issue?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32499667/simpletestcursor-robolectric-3-0-compilation-issue

Comment: For more information/background, see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11333354/how-can-i-test-fragments-with-robolectric/12903280#12903280

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to add the dependency for v4 shadows support. Add this in your dependency file.

```
testCompile "org.robolectric:shadows-support-v4:3.0"
```

Comment: Thanks! I updated my question with this information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11333354/how-can-i-test-fragments-with-robolectric/12903280#12903280